# how to start using res.users in openerp development ?

Tags: android, python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have been developing an openerp module . I have been using python and eclipse IDE for development.
        I have developed a few openerp modules as simple form design for user interface.I wanted to know the use of `res.users` . I have seen this object used many times but I dont really figure out its need and its use . I want to clear it as I am new to openerp development world. I also need a little guidance of how may I use it ? Plz reply me as soon as possible.

Thanks.Hopes for suggestion

Comment: res.users is a table for defining users and their permissions

Answer (score 0):

`res.users` is the model containing all the users of your system and their details. The matching Postgres table is res_users

Use it in a method like:

```
def do_stuff(self, cr, uid, ids, context = None):
   user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context = context)
   print(user.name)
```